# Loop is printing too many times

Tags: dictionary, for-loop

[image]

```
def main():
    lightning = dict()
    with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
        for name,goals,assists in zip(f,f,f):
            lightning[name.strip()] = [int(goals),int(assists)]
        
    f.close()

    title_Player = 'Player'
    title_Goals = 'Goals'
    title_Assists = 'Assists'
    title_Total = 'Total'

    print('{:<10}{:^6}{:^8}{:^6}'.format(title_Player, title_Goals, title_Assists, title_Total))
    highest_points = 0

    for k in lightning:
        goals = lightning[k][0]
        assist = lightning[k][1]
        total = goals + assist
        print('{:<8}'.format(k), end = ' ')
    
        for v in lightning[k]:
            print('{:^6}{:^8}'.format(goals, assist), end = ' ')
        print('{:^6}'.format(total))


        if total > highest_points:
            highest_points = total
            top_scorer = k
    print(top_scorer, 'is the top scorer with', highest_points, 'points')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my code, the goals and assist are displaying twice in the output, I've tried tweaking around with parts of the for loops but haven't had any success. All of the column formatting is correct though.

Comment: What's the use of the 2nd `for` loop? That's why it's printing twice.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Right here:

```
for v in lightning[k]:
        print('{:^6}{:^8}'.format(goals, assist), end = ' ')
```

Since you're iterating through lightning[k] (which has two values, the goals and the assists), you're running that print statement (which prints out both the goals and the assists) twice. Instead, to fit with the header of your table, you should probably just change this:

```
print('{:<8}'.format(k), end = ' ')

for v in lightning[k]:
    print('{:^6}{:^8}'.format(goals, assist), end = ' ')
print('{:^6}'.format(total))
```

to this:

```
print('{:<10}{:^6}{:^8}{:^6}'.format(k, goals, assist, total))
```

which would print the name, the goals, the assists, and the total, all at once, in columns that are the same size as the columns in your header (10, 6, 8, 6).

Answer (score 0):

You need to nix this for loop here:

```
        for v in lightning[k]: <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            print('{:^6}{:^8}'.format(goals, assist), end = ' ')
```

Instead, you can just directly use the print statement.

Breaking down your code to help explain why:

```
    lightning = dict()
    with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
        for name,goals,assists in zip(f,f,f):
            lightning[name.strip()] = [int(goals),int(assists)]
```

Your dictionary is a mapping of `<name : <goals, assists>>`

```
    for k in lightning:
        goals = lightning[k][0]
        assist = lightning[k][1]
        total = goals + assist
        print('{:<8}'.format(k), end = ' ')
```

Here you iterate over your dictionary, this means you're executing this loop once per player, and printing out their name. This is good.

```
        for v in lightning[k]:
            print('{:^6}{:^8}'.format(goals, assist), end = ' ')
        print('{:^6}'.format(total))
```

Here you iterate over the *value* of your dictionary entry, which is the `<goals, assists>` pair from earlier. So you execute this print statement twice!

```
        print('{:^6}'.format(total))
```

And here we're back to printing once, and so you are seeing the total get output only once (as expected).